# Is there a full filterable list of spells by save?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, saving-throw, online-resources

As there are a lot of spells with descriptors and a lot of conditional save bonuses vs certain descriptors, it always leaves me sort of puzzled how good those conditional saves are. Does the internet have a list of spells that can be **organized by what save they target (if any)**, and having the descriptor attached to the spells?

I tried searching google with "pathfinder spells by save" but that results various forums of "how do saves work" questions.
Also tried with this http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/tools/advanced-spell-search/ but it doesn't seem to have anything related to saving throws.

This is related to optimization due to the actual effectiveness of save bonuses that increase vs certain descriptor.